# Asset being built two times with different settings, what can I do?

Tags: xna

In my XNA 3.1 project, I have a cubemap (*.dds) file that seems to be required by almost all of my models in my project. When I go to build my project with the cubemap set to compile into the pipeline, I receive an error going something like this:

> Asset was built 2 times with different settings: using TextureImporter
>   and TextureProcessor, referenced by Models\AlphaDeadTree.X
>   (RacingGameModelProcessor), Models\AlphaPalm.X
>   (RacingGameModelProcessor), Models\AlphaPalm2.X
>   (RacingGameModelProcessor), Models\AlphaPalm3.X
>   (RacingGameModelProcessor)...

And so on and so forth. Several google results mention that simply removing the file from the Content node, while retaining the physical file in its directory will solve the problem, however, it seems as though it's no longer loaded into the Content pipeline once it's removed from the project's Content node, despite the models requiring that file.

At this point, what can I do? Is my only option to ignore that gigantic warning message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see on your Content.contentproject that you still direct reference model textures (textures\SkyCubeMap.dds, Shaders\Textures\NormalizeCubeMap.dds, ...): this is not correct. From your content project you only have to reference models (*.X) but not textures (*.tga, *.dds, etc.) used by the models. Don't worry for those textures: they will automatically be located, imported and processed.

For example, if you have a model called Tank.X and that model uses a texture called Tank.dds you only have to include Tank.X in your content project. Including Tank.dds will produce the error.

On the other hand, you will have to include on your content project textures that you are going to load *by hand*: **Content.Load("MyByHandLoadedTexture");**

If you need to load the same texture from a model and by hand you will have to duplicate it and make the models use one copy and include the other copy in the content project in order to be loaded by hand.

Comment: Ah, excellent! I just found an entire code file that was dedicated to loading and handling that cube map file. It all makes sense now, thank you so much.

I guess an important lesson learned here is that you really learn code when you make it yourself, as opposed to modifying templates and pre-created projects. But thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can right click the texture and in the properties dialog look for the 'Build Action' option and set to 'None'. This works for me in XNA 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The cubemap is built twice because it's referenced by one or more models (firs time) and because it's referenced explicitly by your content project (second time).

Try to remove it from your content project but CAUTION, don't click it and press "delete": this would remove it from the disk. Right-click it and, from the contextual menu, select "exclude from project" (or something similar... I use a localized version of Visual Studio and don't know the exact option label in english).

Comment: Sorry, excluding from my project was what I was implying by saying "removing from the content node". If I do that, the file comes up missing, according to the debugger. It gets built with a _0 appended to the file name.

Comment: Are all models being processed with RacingGameModelProcessor? 

Did you double checked that no other reference to the cubemap is still on the content project tree (on other folder)? You can verify it by editing the Content.contentproject file in a text editor (notepad?) and doing a search (Ctrl+F).

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. It turns out that it _was_ being added twice in my content tree. After removing the second one, I still receive the same error message, though. It seems that all models are being processed by the RacingGameModelProcessor, then it hands off the execution of each processing back to ModelProcessor to finish up anything that it has to do (I'm pretty much quoting the comments in the code at that point, would it help it I posted it?)

Comment: It would help to take a look at those comments. Also would help to see the Content.contentproject file.

Comment: I'm going to have to pastebin the code, here it is. [link](http://pastebin.com/zA5MkQcn)

Also, here is the Content.contentproj file: [link](http://pastebin.com/EkSZc1uv)

Comment: Edit: Looks like I completely forgot to upgrade the solution from XNA 3.0 to 3.1. I'll try upgrading it to see if that fixes anything.